# AffineTransformOp speed/memory question

Tags: java, filter, affinetransform

I have asked this question before, but I wanted to rephrase/clarify some points and expand upon it.  I have a piece of code which transforms a BufferedImage using an AffineTransform.

```
op = new AffineTransformOp(atx, interactive ? interpolationInteractive : interpolationNormal);
displayImage = op.filter(displayImage, null);
```

This code works fine, however it causes a memory accumulation.  Specifically, every time this piece of code is called more memory is stored up.  I have tried the other form of filter as well.

```
op = new AffineTransformOp(atx, interactive ? interpolationInteractive : interpolationNormal);
displayImage2 = op.createCompatibleDestImage(displayImage, displayImage.getColorModel());
op.filter(displayImage, displayImage2);
```

However, this is much much slower than the first version.  I want the speed of the first version with the memory usage of the second.

1. How can I clean up after the first version?  Specifically, where are the intermediate BufferedImages stored, and how can I delete them?
2. Why is the second version slower than the first?  What can I do to speed it up?

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Are you actually getting OutOfMemoryErrors? If not, then it's just a matter of when the GC collects the objects, not an actual memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you getting `displayImage` and what `ColorModel` is it using?

If it is an `IndexColorModel`, that may explain a lot.

The first code fragment will return a `BufferedImage` using a `DirectColorModel`. That will require 4 bytes per pixel vs typically 1-byte per pixel for an indexed image. That 1:4 expansion could be causing your out of memory condition.

The second code fragment makes a `BufferedImage` with the same model as the source. When that is an `IndexColorModel` and the interpolation is not `NEAREST_NEIGHBOR`, the `filter()` call will create a temporary `BufferedImage` with a `DirectColorModel`. It will use that as the destination of the filter operation, then requantize the temporary buffer and draw it into your `displayImage2`. So, twice as many bitblits.

If you're only doing a single transform, I'd say go with the second form.

If you're doing multiple operations, allocate a pair of `BufferedImage`s with a `DirectColorModel`. large enough to hold your biggest image. Draw you source image into one of them and perform your filters back and forth between them. Then when you're finished, use a `ColorConvertOp` to requantize back to an indexed image. That way you only need to color convert once instead of on each filter call.

Comment: I think I'll try your second suggestion first, can you tell me how to use ColorConvertOp to convert from a direct to an indexed color model?

Comment: ColorConvertOp work just like AffineTransformOp, but you need to call `filter(src, dst)` passing `dst` as an existing `BufferedImage` of the desired color model.

Comment: OK, but how do you use the constructor from the ColorConvertOp.  I did the following
    ColorModel indexColorModel = displayImage.getColorModel();
    displayImage = op.filter(displayImage, null);
    ColorConvertOp colorOp = new ColorConvertOp(indexColorModel.getColorSpace(), displayImage.getColorModel().getColorSpace(), null);
    displayImage = colorOp.filter(displayImage, null);

And when I run this it just hangs on the filter line, never returning.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mistyped one of the lines of code above, it should actually read
ColorModel indexColorModel = displayImage.getColorModel(); displayImage = op.filter(displayImage, null); ColorConvertOp colorOp = new ColorConvertOp(displayImage.getColorModel().getColorSpace(), indexColorModel.getColorSpace(), null); displayImage = colorOp.filter(displayImage, null);

I mixed up the order of the parameters in the ColorConvertOp constructor, but it is still incredibly slow.

Comment: I've always used the simple "hints only" constructor: ColorConvertOp  colorOp  = ColorConvertOp (null); Then pass in a BI with the desired color space for the destination.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment that unless you're getting OutOfMemoryErrors, then this is a normal thing and the GC will collect the images whenever it sees fit.  Here's a silly test I did sometimes when I had a concern: put that into loop in a main function and watch the memory usage in a profiler (it should make a zig-zag-like pattern or something) but not always be able to complete successfully.

Comment: I am getting out of memory issues.  I was able to slow it down by running System.finalization and System.gc when the memory got too high (I have a thread which tracks memory management).

Comment: If you have it working now, then that's fine, although it's concerning to me that you have a thread tracking memory management - it's like you're trying to re-create Java's memory management and it won't be as good anyways.  This will sound silly, but are you not allocating enough space on the heap?  When I was using a lot of image tranforms, I had to allocate 512 or 1024, I think, before it was a comfortable user experience.  You can also set many parameters related to memory and the GC in the JVM - try here: http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc5.0/gc_tuning_5.html